# Python: sorting and appending list without changing order

Tags: python, sorting, mapping

I have two lists, let's say:

```
[[37.1, -122.1], [37.2,-122.2], [37.3,-122.3]]
```

&

```
[[37.3, -122.3], [38.1,-123.1], [38.2,-123.2]]
```

I need to check if the **first OR last** item in that list of lats/lngs is the same as another **first OR last** pair.

In this case the last pair of the first list `[37.3,-122.3]` equals the first pair of the second.

I would need to append the second list to the first excluding the first lat/lng pair without changing the order of the second list, unless the result is like in the edited version.

This is important since it forms a line to be drawn on a map.

The end result would be :

```
[[37.1, -122.1], [37.2,-122.2], [37.3, -122.3], [38.1,-123.1], [38.2,-123.2]]
```

This would need to be a scalable approach as I have dozens of these that need to be based on each other.

**Edit**

The answers I've gotten are great, but it has to check only first or last, and it has to reverse the order if the result is list2[-1] == list1[0]

Another example.

```
[[37.1, -122.1], [37.2,-122.2], [37.3,-122.3]]
```

&

```
[[37.3, -122.3], [38.1,-123.1], [38.2,-123.2]]
```

&

```
[[37.1, -122.1], [39.1,-124.1], [39.2,-124.2]]
```

In this instance, the resulting list would be

`[[39.2,-124.2], [39.1,-124.1], [37.1, -122.1], [37.2,-122.2], [37.3,-122.3], [38.1,-123.1], [38.2,-123.2]]`

Comment: I like the two solutions if it was only these two lists, but I have a list of dozens of these and it has to check for a match in every single one of those lists.

Answer (score 0):

you could use an  `if` statement:

```
line1 = [[37.1, -122.1], [37.2,-122.2], [37.3,-122.3]]
line2 = [[37.3, -122.3], [38.1,-123.1], [38.2,-123.2]]

result = [] # in case that first/last do not match
if line1[-1] == line2[0]:
    result = line1 + line2[1:]
elif line2[-1] == line1[0]:
    result = line2 + line1[1:]

print(result)
```

output:

```
[[37.1, -122.1], [37.2, -122.2], [37.3, -122.3], [38.1, -123.1], [38.2, -123.2]]
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, unfortunately this won't work. Check the edit for clarification. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
list_1 = [[37.1, -122.1], [37.2,-122.2], [37.3,-122.3]]
list_2 = [[37.3, -122.3], [38.1,-123.1], [38.2,-123.2]]

for i in list_2:
    if i not in list_1:
        list_1.append(i)

print(list_1)

>>> [[37.1, -122.1], [37.2, -122.2], [37.3, -122.3], [38.1, -123.1], [38.2, -123.2]]
```

Comment: This won't work, since the middle one can be the same and that will mess it up. The order has to stay the same and the entire list has to be appended in the same order.